# How to customize bootstrap columns with the same class name?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, css-selectors

I am trying to use the same `.col-5` in the same row (for sizing purposes), but I don't know the best way to go about changing the background color for each individual column, since the columns are the same name (this will change the styles of all columns).

> Edit: I want to do much more than change background colors so a simple
>   span tag is not optimal.

What is the best practice way to handle this issue? Assume I am linked to bootstrap and my own custom .css file:

```
<body>


    <header>
      <div class="logo"><h1>Name</h1></div>
    </header>



    <div id="sideBar">

    </div>



    <div id="rowContainer1">

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-5">
          Hello
        </div>
        <div class="col-5">
          Hello
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>



    <div id="rowContainer2">

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-5">
          Hello
        </div>
        <div class="col-5">
          Hello
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>



  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: add just another class, something like <div class="col-5 red">, <div class="col-5 white">, etc

Comment: "I want to do much more than change background colors so a simple span tag is not optimal." What do you want to do? Are you looping results from a database? Why not just give each col a unique ID and style based upon that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this via jQuery without unique id, but it might be easier to manage if you can use ids.

```
.col-red { background-color: red; }
.col-green { background-color: green; }

$("#rowContainer1 div[class=col-5]").eq(1).addClass("col-red");
```

[JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/shweobj3/3/)

Comment: that's pretty awesome. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can add different classes for each column.

```css
.col-red { background-color: red; }
.col-green { background-color: green; }
```

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div class="row">
  <div class="col-5 col-red">
    RED
  </div>
  <div class="col-5 col-green">
    GREEN
  </div>
</div>
```